# Sending Canvas ImageData through AJAX crashes Google Chrome

Tags: ajax, jquery, canvas

If I create a large Canvas and add data to it (say, 1024x768) then try to post the imagedata for it through AJAX to a PHP file (in order to save it to a file), the tab crashes in Google Chrome.

In Firefox, the tab itself doesn't crash, but the PHP file appears to have been called with no POST variables.

Is this just too big a task to attempt, or am I doing something wrong? I realise that there's a lot of data involved.

Comment: Could you provide some code? I'm primarily interested in how you pass the data to server.

Comment: I know that it's an old problem. But I'm stuck with the same problem. It's all crashing here did you find any solution for it? thanks.

Comment: I believe in the end I worked out an alternative solution, possibly involving saving the bytes to the local FS in the FE, then uploading the saved file. It was quite a while back though, so my memory is a bit fuzzy, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Was having a similar issue, and I found that the toDataURL() string was too long for my web server to handle, and it was a suhosin setting that I could not alter.  By testing canvas.toDataURL().length, I found that the breaking point was around 950,000 characters. I made a function that tests the toDataURL string length, and if it's over 900,000, it resizes down until it's a size the server can handle.

Obviously the result is a smaller image than the original, but it worked for my purposes.  Hope it helps:

```
/*Make sure origImg is a global variable, the first parameter 
you are sending to the function is an image object and the first size
parameter is 100*/

var origImg = new Image();
origImg.src = canvas.toDataURL();

var canvasDataForServer = makeSmallCanvas(origImg,100);

function makeSmallCanvas(orig,size) {
  var img = orig;
  img.width = img.width * (size / 100);
  img.height = img.height * (size / 100);

  var smallCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  smallCanvas.width = img.width;
  smallCanvas.height = img.height;
  sctx = smallCanvas.getContext('2d');
  sctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);

  var retStr = smallCanvas.toDataURL();
  if(retStr.length < 900000) {
    return retStr;
  } else {
    return makeSmallCanvas(origImg,size-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me :( , still getting big images. And If I reduce the length number the function stops working.